# Formato de Logger

Tags: java, date, formato, logger

Después de pelearme bastante con la clase `java.util.Logger` y todas las que lo rodean, he llegado a construirme un *logger* que me escribe los eventos que le mando en un archivo log, en formato [xml](/questions/tagged/xml). El cual pego aquí:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
  <date>2020-05-03T12:37:56.308154Z</date>
  <millis>1588509476308</millis>
  <nanos>154000</nanos>
  <sequence>9209</sequence>
  <level>SEVERE</level>
  <class>regir.GestorArchivos</class>
  <method>setMensaje</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Texto del mensaje de error es grande grande grande grande</message>
</record>
```

Hay varios campos que no deseo que se me guarden. El campo `millis`, el campo `nanos`, el campo `class` y el campo `method`.

Ya que la clase y el método que van a mandar los logs cuando ponga mi clase Logger en producción, irá incluido en el mensaje.
Por otra parte, la fecha la quiero en el formato `DD/MM/YYYY 24:00:00` (horas en 24H (17, no 5), minutos en 2 dígitos siempre(03, no 3) y segundos en 2 dígitos siempre(06, no 6)). Y no deseo decimales de segundo.

El campo Thread aún no se si lo quiero o no, tendría que ponerlo en producción y probarlo. Tengo varios Threads que llamarán a la clase que he construido que hereda de Logger.

Y por ahora no tengo ni idea de cómo conseguir este formato de XML sólo con el texto que me interesa.

Comment: y como se llama la librería que usas?

Comment: Estoy utilizando java.util.logging.Logger. La clase LogRecord creo que está relacionada con cada uno de los registros, y tiene un método llamado setParameters(Object[] parameters) que creo que podría estar relacionado. Pero he intentado con él y no he sabido hacerlo.

Comment: No es la respuesta, pero podrías probar con apache commons-logging y peleas menos, en vez de reinventar la rueda :)

Comment: Tu archivo lo estas creando manual ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma de implementar esto es extender la clase *XMLFormatter* (java.util.logging.XMLFormatter). Esta clase se encarga de decirle a logger qué campos y cómo debe realizar el guardado de cada registro. Sobreescribiendo el método *format*, puede especificar como es que debe ser guardado cada registro.

Te paso la forma de resolver tu planteo:

Primero, creamos una clase MyXMLFormatter que extiende de XMLFormatter:

```
// Reemplaza este package con el nombre donde lo implementes
package com.bc.logger; 

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class MyXMLFormatter extends XMLFormatter {

    // Sobreescribimos el método format:
    public String format(LogRecord record) {

        // He removido los campos que indicaste que no necesitas
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);
        sb.append("<record>\n");

        sb.append("  <date>");
        // Aqui se especifica la fecha en el formato que desees.
        sb.append((new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date(record.getMillis())));
        sb.append("</date>\n");

        sb.append("  <secuence>");
        escape(sb, String.valueOf(record.getSequenceNumber()));
        sb.append("</secuence>\n");

        sb.append("  <level>");
        escape(sb, record.getLevel().toString());
        sb.append("</level>\n");

        // Este es el registro del numero de thread, 
        // si no lo necesitas luego, puedes eliminarlo:
        sb.append("  <thread>");
        sb.append(record.getThreadID());
        sb.append("</thread>\n");

        if (record.getMessage() != null) {

            String message = formatMessage(record);
            sb.append("  <message>");
            escape(sb, message);
            sb.append("</message>");
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        sb.append("</record>\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void escape(StringBuilder sb, String text) {
        if (text == null) {
            text = "<null>";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char ch = text.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '<') {
                sb.append("&lt;");
            } else if (ch == '>') {
                sb.append("&gt;");
            } else if (ch == '&') {
                sb.append("&amp;");
            } else {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Luego, puedes utilizarlo de éste modo. Este es mi archivo Prueba.java, donde registro logs utilizando el formatter anterior:

```
package com.bc.prueba;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

// Si has cambiado el paquete de la clase anterior, recuerda
// ajustarlo también aquí:
import com.bc.logger.MyXMLFormatter;

class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("Prueba");
        FileHandler myLogFileHandler;

        try {
            // Puedes cambiar el nombre y path de tu archivo de log aquí:
            myLogFileHandler = new FileHandler("logfile.xml", true);
            myLogger.addHandler(myLogFileHandler);

            // Utilizamos nuestro formatter:
            MyXMLFormatter myformatter = new MyXMLFormatter();
            myLogFileHandler.setFormatter(myformatter);

            // Agregamos 100 lineas de log
            int n = 1;
            while (n <= 100) {
                myLogger.info("Agregando linea: " + n);
                Thread.sleep(100);
                n++;
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Al finalizar la ejecución, veras que te genera un archivo *logfile.xml* con el siguiente formato:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
    <date>08/05/2020 12:21:11</date>
    <secuence>0</secuence>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <thread>1</thread>
    <message>Agregando linea: 1</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>08/05/2020 12:21:11</date>
    <secuence>1</secuence>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <thread>1</thread>
    <message>Agregando linea: 2</message>
</record>
...
```

Comment: Me parece excelente esta solución usando una clase que extiende de XMLFormatter.

Comment: Me está ayudando mucho a entender lo que quiero hacer. Me ha resultado muy facil añadir la clase y el método que provoca el log, y quitar esta info del mensaje. Ahora me falta probarlo en alguna de mis clases. Pondré noticias cuando lo haya probado.

Comment: Cada vez que ejecuto el programa, si el archivo de log existe me añade, al principio de cada vez que uso el log, las líneas:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd"> Esto se puede evitar, y que sólo estén 1 única vez por archivo?